# How to test if all classes that might be imported are on classpath at runtime?

Tags: java, testing, deployment, ant

I'm writing an `ant` build script to prepare my program to be webstart deployable. It consists of a few of my jar files as well as >50 3rd party jar files. The approach I'm taking for writing my build script is to run my `main` method and monkey with it to see if I can induce a `NoClassDefFoundError`, add the missing jar to my build script, and then repeat. I guess you could describe this as `smoke testing`.

Is there an automated way of doing this? `javac` was able to verify that all classes were available at compile time; is there a similar tool I could use at runtime?

Comment: Think about using a tool with dependency management, like Maven or Gradle. Then you pull your indirect dependencies automatically and avoid most of the NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: We have been considering Gradle, but we haven't taken the time to set that up yet. Can it auto-detect dependencies?

Comment: In Gradle, you only specify your DIRECT dependencies, i.e. those that you actually use in the source code. Without them, you cannot compile. Gradle searches the indirect dependencies for you, so you will not get NoClassDefFoundError. On the other hand, this only works if you pull your direct dependencies from a repository like maven central (not from the file system).

Comment: If you have the luxury of choosing an alternative build tool then Grade is a good option. Alternatively Apache ivy is an ANT plugin that would provide dependency management without the need to re-write all your build logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a utility that loads

```
Class.forName("your.Class")
```

all the user classes (those which are added by you), and keep an eye for Exception in class loading, this will cover all static class loading cases,

This part will get covered by well managed dependency management tool like Maven

But it will not cover the cases where you are dynamically loading classes from your source for that JVM has to exercise that part of code